# "Token expired" Obtaining Google Auth Token

Tags: android

I'm getting the following error back when trying to get a google auth token by using

```
AccountManagerFuture<Bundle> amf = am.getAuthToken(
    accounts[0], "finance", null, activity[0], null, null
);

try
{
    auth_token = amf.getResult().getString("authtoken");
    Log.v("PORTFOLIO", "getting token...: "+auth_token);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I get a valid-looking token, but then when I try and use it, I get a "Token expired" error back:

```
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): <HTML>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): <HEAD>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): <TITLE>Token expired</TITLE>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): </HEAD>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): <H1>Token expired</H1>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): <H2>Error 401</H2>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): </BODY>
V/PORTFOLIO(11970): </HTML>
```

Along with:

```
W/DefaultRequestDirector(11970): Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges: {googlelogin=WWW-Authenticate: GoogleLogin realm="http://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin", service="finance"}
```

I'm a little confused why this is happening, as it was working properly before. How do I get a "non-expired" token? I'm probably doing something terribly wrong. If anyone has a link to a proper auth token tutorial, that would help too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I need to use `invalidateAuthToken()`.